# What is the meaning of 'hostage' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

It's from

http://www.newscientist.com/blogs/shortsharpscience/2010/11/pain-brain-regions-also-active.html

> Consequently, the concept of dysfunction is systemically `hostage` to
>   political dynamics and social power

Thanks,

Comment: Note that the comment seems to come from an essentially Marxist viewpoint, insisting that this study of female sexuality must be interpreted, or rather, invalidated, within the framework of Marxist ideas of oppression and liberation—specifically the oppression of women by men.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that people who are in power can decide what is called *bad* or *disordered.*

hostage 
n.
 
3. One [or something] that is under the constraining control of another: "In becoming a mother one becomes a hostage to fortune" (Janna Malamud Smith).

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hostage